# python multiple output variables as input

Tags: python

```
def function_1(a,b,c,d):
    print('{}{}{}{}'.format(a,b,c,d))
    return

def function_2():
   t=y=u=i= 5
   return t,y,u,i

function_1(function_2())
```

I expect that python would execute function 2 first, and return each t, y, u and i as inputs to function1, but instead I get:

```
TypeError: function_1() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'b', 'c', and 'd'
```

I understand that either the output of function2 is in a single object, or it is treating function2 as an input function, instead of executing.

how do I change my code to execute as expected? (each of the output variables from function2 treated as input variables to function1)

Comment: Also *THANK YOU* for producing a minimal complete verifiable example. That's a *huge* thing that adds to ease of answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a splat operator.

```
function_1(*function_2())
```

`function_2()` returns a tuple `(5, 5, 5, 5)`. To pass that as a set of four parameters (rather than one four-element tuple as one parameter), you use the splat operator `*`

Closely related is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a slightly awkward way of doing it, but you can actually pss the function as a parameter itself, and then decompose it!

```
def function_1(func):
    print('{}{}{}{}'.format(*func))
    return

def function_2():
   t=y=u=i= 5
   return t,y,u,i

function_1(function_2())
```

output:

```
5555
```